# How do I loop over each row in a pandas groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] , 'b' : ['cat_1', 'cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_2', 'cat_2']})`

I perform a groupby:

`df.groupby(['b']).agg(['count', 'median'])`

I would like to iterate through the rows that this call returns, for example:

```
for row in ?:
    print(row)
```

should print something like:

```
('cat_1', 2, 1.5)
('cat_2', 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've misunderstood: `df.groupby(['b']).agg(['count', 'median'])` returns an in-memory **dataframe**, *not* an **iterator** of groupwise results.

Your result is often expressed in this way:

```
res = df.groupby('b')['a'].agg(['count', 'median'])

print(res)

#        count  median
# b                   
# cat_1      2     1.5
# cat_2      3     4.0
```

Iterating a dataframe is possible via [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) or, more efficiently, [`itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
for row in df.groupby('b')['a'].agg(['count', 'median']).itertuples():
    print((row.Index, row.count, row.median))

print(res)

# ('cat_1', 2, 1.5)
# ('cat_2', 3, 4.0)
```

If you are looking to calculate lazily, iterate a `groupby` object and perform your calculations on each group independently. For data that fits comfortably in memory, you should expect this to be slower than iterating a dataframe of results.

```
for key, group in df.groupby('b'):
    print((key, group['a'].count(), group['a'].median()))

# ('cat_1', 2, 1.5)
# ('cat_2', 3, 4.0)
```

If you do face memory issues, consider [`dask.dataframe`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) for such tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
for item in df.groupby(['b']).agg(['count', 'median']).reset_index().values:
     # Perform operation on 'item' ...
```