# Traversing groups of group by object pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need help with some big pandas issue.

As a lot of people asked to have the real input and real desired output in order to answer the question, there it goes:
So I have the following dataframe

```
Date          user  cumulative_num_exercises  total_exercises %_exercises   
2017-01-01     1            2                      7             28,57
2017-01-01     2            1                      7             14.28
2017-01-01     4            3                      7             42,85
2017-01-01     10           1                      7             14,28
2017-02-02     1            2                      14            14,28
2017-02-02     2            3                      14            21,42
2017-02-02     4            4                      14            28,57
2017-02-02     10           5                      14            35,71
2017-03-03     1            3                      17            17,64
2017-03-03     2            3                      17            17,64
2017-03-03     4            5                      17            29,41
2017-03-03     10           6                      17            35,29

%_exercises_accum
28,57
42,85
85,7
100
14,28
35,7
64,27
100
17,64
35,28
64,69
100
```

-The column %_exercises is the value of the column (cumulative_num_exercises/total_exercises)*100
-The column %_exercises_accum is the value of the sum of the %_exercises **for each month**. (Note that at the end of each month, it reaches the value 100).

-I need to calculate, whith this data, the % of users that contributed to do a 50%, 80% and 90% of the total exercises, during each month.

-In order to do so, I have thought to create a new column, called category, which will later be used to count how many users contributed to each of the 3 percentages (50%, 80% and 90%). The category column takes the following values:

- 0 if the user did a %_exercises_accum  = 0.
- 1 if the user did a %_exercises_accum < 50 and > 0.
- 50 if the user did a %_exercises_accum = 50.
- 80 if the user did a %_exercises_accum = 80.
- 90 if the user did a %_exercises_accum = 90.

And so on, because there are many cases in order to determine who contributes to which percentage of the total number of exercises on each month.

I have already determined all the cases and all the values that must be taken.

Basically, I traverse the dataframe using a **for loop**, and with **two main ifs**:

if (df.iloc[i][date] == df.iloc[i][date].shift()):

calculations to determine the percentage or percentages to which the user from the second to the last row of the same month group contributes
     (because the same user can contribute to all the percentages, or to more  than one)

else:

calculations to determine to which percentage of exercises the first 
member of each 
month group contributes.

The calculations involve:

1. Looking at the value of the category column in the previous row using shift().
2. Doing while loops inside the for, because when a user suddenly reaches a big percentage, we need to go back for the users in the same month, and change their category_column value to 50, as they have contributed to the 50%, but didn't reach it. for instance, in this situation:

   Date     %_exercises_accum
       2017-01-01       1,24
       2017-01-01       3,53
       2017-01-01       20,25
       2017-01-01       55,5

The desired output for the given dataframe at the beginning of the question would include the same columns as before (date, user, cumulative_num_exercises, total_exercises, %_exercises and %_exercises_accum) plus the category column, which is the following:

```
category
50
50
508090
90
50
50
5080
8090
50
50
5080
8090
```

Note that the rows with the values: 508090, or 8090, mean that that user is contributing to create:

1. 508090: both 50%, 80% and 90% of total exercises in a month.
2. 8090: both 80% and 90% of exercises in a month.

Does anyone know how can I simplify this for loop by traversing the groups of a group by object?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "As it is too complex to explain".  How are we supposed to answer if you can't explain to us what we are answering?

Comment: The real issue is whether there is a way of traversing the rows of a group by object or not. Trust me, you don't want to read what the whole calculation is about XD

Comment: If the question is about traversing the rows of a groupby object, none of the other information should be in the question, since it's really not relevant, and that question [has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244171/how-do-i-loop-over-each-row-in-a-pandas-groupby).

Comment: It is relevant, since I want people to know what kind of operations this big calculation involves, and how does the dataframe look like, as traversing the groups done by date could be easier once the dates are already ordered together. :).

Comment: You need to come up with a simpler calculation as a stand-in. The risk here is that iterating over each group may not be the correct way to apply the calculation in pandas.

Comment: you probably think that transposing or transversing the df is the best way to work, why don't you post your input and intended output and people can work with that. That's usually the best method of working in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Given no sense of what calculations you wish to accomplish, this is my best guess at what you're looking for. However, I'd re-iterate [Datanovice's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938627/traversing-groups-of-group-by-object-pandas#comment98530627_55938627) that the best way to get answers is to provide a sample output.

You can slice to each unique date using the following code:

```
dates = ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-01-01','2017-02-02','2017-02-02','2017-02-02','2017-02-02','2017-03-03','2017-03-03','2017-03-03','2017-03-03']
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date':pd.to_datetime(dates),
     'user': [1,2,4,10,1,2,4,10,1,2,4,10],
     'cumulative_num_exercises':[2,1,3,1,2,3,4,5,3,3,5,6],
     'total_exercises':[7,7,7,7,14,14,14,14,17,17,17,17]}
)

df = df.set_index('date')

for idx in df.index.unique():
    hold = df.loc[idx]

    ### YOUR CODE GOES HERE ###
```